# Change web app locale with url routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, zend-framework2

I'm developing a web app with Zend Framework 2.

How can i change the application locale based on current url?

I already match urls like domain/locale/controller/action/etc. but i don't know where put code to analyse current url and change locale accordingly!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could use a $_GET parameter in your url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $_GET isn't for parameters? I don't have the locale as parameter, but as part of url, i.e. mysite.com/en/main/index. Anyway i already know what code i should write, what i don't understand is WHERE i should put that code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
../config/autoload/local.php

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segment = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
$locale = $segment[1];

if($locale == '')
    $locale = 'en_US'; // default locale

return array(
     'translator' => array(
         'locale' => $locale,
         ),
);
```